# How do I bind microservices in Lagom to something other than localhost?

Tags: lagom

I am developing several microservices using Lagom. Each exposes a set of REST endpoints. All default implementations that I have seen bind to localhost. How do I bind specific services to different hosts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lagomServiceAddress` setting key in SBT or the `serviceAddress` tag in Maven. For more information, see [here](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/java/ConfiguringServicesInDevelopment.html#How-are-addresses-bound-by-services?). Note that this is for *development* -- using a container orchestration mechanism is recommended for deployment.